# Is it possible to remove the title bar in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there any way to remove the title bar of Sublime Text 3? Much like how it looks in full screen mode but not needing to be set to full screen is what Im looking for.

I have looked through the settings but cant seem to find anything.

I am using OS X.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Try this: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/chrome-less-sublime/1125/16

Comment: "Much like how it looks in full screen mode [...]" For those that might be coming from google in the future, I found that Full Screen mode is pretty much exactly what I was looking for when I clicked the link for this answer.